# Parse Function Returning Empty Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, parse-server

I'm calling a Parse cloud method from our front-end, but rather than the expected test return of "123", I am receiving a blank array.

The method pushes to an array called 'promiseArray' the String "123". Front end is receiving "[]" rather than "["123"]"

Code (reduced for relevancy):

```
Parse.Cloud.define('newReport', function(req, res) {

try{

for (let i = 0; i < fEPath.length; i++) {

  let outputPart;

  switch(fEPath[i].elementName){

    case 'testOutput':
    promiseArray.push(
      "123"
    );
    break

  }
}
```

We use the syntax:

```
Promise.all(promiseArray).then(values => {
  res.success(values);
});
```

To send the array back to the front-end.

Comment: Have you verified fEPath[i].elementName === ‘testOutput’?  That could cause it not to push value “123” into our array

Comment: are you executing `Promise.all(promiseArray)` before `newReport` is even executed perhaps? your code doesn't show where this `newReport` is used

Answer (score 1):

Your return value should be a Promise object. Try this:

```
case 'testOutput':
    promiseArray.push(
        new Promise(
            function (resolve, reject) {
                resolve("123")
            }
        )
    );
break
```